# Laravel Eloquent Joins use of belongs to

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 table for get inner join query records in laravel eloquent, but is not working with combine data get.

**Table :category**

1. id
2. name
3. cat_status

**Table:image**

1. id
2. title
3. desc
4. img_status

#image controller

```
//get all active images    
ImageModel::where('status',true)->get();     
public function getCategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Api\CategoryModel','cat_id');
}
```

#get category active only

```
public function getActiveCategory() {
    return $this->getCategory()->where('cat_status','=', 1);
}
```

I need to get only which category is active, that images only.

```
if cat 1,2,3   3(is inactive)
image table
title=a1,cat_id=1,
title=a2,cat_id=2,
title=a3,cat_id=3
```

Now I get all 3 images , i need only first 2, because cat_id 3 is inactive .
Any ideas how I can join the status condition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your belongs to method should me in Model not in controller.

Comment: Sorry .. i added wrongly .. paste in controller part here. Belongs to condition is model.

Comment: You can use eager loading option to retrieve. Its pretty clear in the doc

Answer (score 0):

Well relation methods doesn't provides joins. You have to do it manually.
If You want to get IMAGES from active categories then You''ll have to query like this:

```
// method from image model
public function getImagesFromActiveCategory() {
    return $this->join('category')
        ->select('image.*')
        ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'image.cat_id')
        ->where('cat_status','=', 1)
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your giving the quick responses,
I tried to use other but  is solved now with the use of belongsToMany Method.
Below functions gives exact records from the DB, which match with each category and images table, and category status active records only.

```
#Image Controller
 $images=  ImageModel::where('status',true)->get();
  foreach($images as $img){
    #get data
    $onlyactiveCategoryImages=$img->getActiveCategory()->get();
  } 

#image Model

   #get category data
    public function getCategory() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Api\CategoryModel','images','id','cat_id');
    }

    #get category active only
       public function getActiveCategory() {
        return $this->getCategory()->where('cat_status','=', 1);
    }
```

Thank you once again for all :).